# Large SQL OR statement or filter in code?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Say I have a large array of IDs, about 10,000 items long. Each ID is a unique string composed of numbers, around 20 characters long.

`['438122955667406858', '427968416155041792', '427968416155041792', '387734570570743849'...]`

I also have a database table, where IDs correspond to IDs in the array. The IDs in the table are **not** unique, an the table can have multiple rows where the ID matches, like this:
[image]

So the problem comes in here: The array of 10,000 IDs are divided amongst 10 or so processes, so each process has its share of ~1000, unique IDs. Each process must request from the database of 20+k entries, any row where its ID is among the processes' share of IDs.

The final question would be, would it be better to construct a large [Op.or] statement, letting the SQL server do the work:

```
table.findAll({
    where: {
        guild: {
            [Op.or]: ThousandIDArray,
        }
    }
}).then(rows => rows.forEach(r => doSomething()))
```

or requesting all the rows, and filtering it manually per-process?

```
table.findAll().then(rows => {
    rows.forEach(r => {
        if (ThousandIDArray.includes(r.guild)) doSomething();
    })
})
```

Comment: is guild id indexed?

Comment: let the db do the processing; do not return all that data over the wire

Comment: @RaymondNijland The guild ids are not indexed in either the database or in the array, their order is as good as random.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are not saving anything by splitting the work into sets of 1000 ids. It would be simpler to just place all the ids of interest in a single array and do something like the following:

```
let result = await [model].findAll({
    where: {
        [Op.in]: [uuid, uuid, uuid, uuid, ...]
    }
});
```

[Sequelize Operators](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators)